# Disable cache website for javascript.js files

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a web app where I do updates constantly.

All my js files for a web pages are in this format to force no cache from browser:

```
<script src="./js/scripts.js?v=1.1"></script>
```

where ?v=1.x is incremented on each modify of my js.

The problem is that sometime some users tell me the page doesn't work (like form not submitted after fields check: stuck and other problems...). I tell him to reload page with CTRL+F5 and try again.... all works great.

I've read already some post about caching and this is the method used from all people: querying with `?v=....`

But in my case some browser seems to not view this changed url and reload js from cache instead reload it. Why?

Why the browser doesn't reload all my js when url is changed??

Comment: It is not a duplicate post: i already do the wuering method but it seem some PC (or browser) doesn't reload files!